# How to take pictures using webcam in java

Tags: java, webcam

Is there is a way to take photos using a web camera in java?. I fond some ways but that,s not work

Answer (score 2):

You need to configured javacv:-

[Click here](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2017/01/javacv-configuration-in-windows.html)

Please find below example how we configured javacv :-

```
  import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.IplImage;

import java.io.File;

import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_core.cvFlip;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.helper.opencv_imgcodecs.cvSaveImage;

public class Test implements Runnable {
    final int INTERVAL = 100;///you may use interval
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");

    public Test() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run() {

        new File("images").mkdir();

        FrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0); // 1 for next camera
        OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
        IplImage img;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            grabber.start();

            while (true) {
                Frame frame = grabber.grab();

                img = converter.convert(frame);

                //the grabbed frame will be flipped, re-flip to make it right
                cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise

                //save
                cvSaveImage("images" + File.separator + (i++) + "-aa.jpg", img);

                canvas.showImage(converter.convert(img));

                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test gs = new Test();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```